# How can I imitate the style of a certain 3D bar chart?

Tags: plotting, charts

I would like to get a 3D visualization of a given matrix.

Here is a figure which may come from *Mathematica*. I want to plot something like it. When I use `ListPlot3D` or `BarChart3D` to plot my matrix, it does not have the style of one shown below, which is what I'm look for. How can I do a nice 3D visualization of my matrix?

[image: visualization of a matrix]

```
data = ( {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {5, 4, 8},
    {2, 5, 7}
   } );

data = ArrayPad[data, {0, 1}];
xTicks = {{1.5, "A"}, {2.5, "B"}, {3.5, "C"}};
yTicks = {{1.5, "X"}, {2.5, "Y"}, {3.5, "Z"}};
zTicks = {{0, "0"}, 0, {4, "4"}, {8, "8"}};

pic = ListPlot3D[data, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  Filling -> Bottom,
  FillingStyle -> {Opacity[0.9]},
  PlotRange -> {Min[data] - 0.5, Max[data] + 0.2},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5},
  Ticks -> {xTicks, yTicks, zTicks},
  DataRange -> All,
  Boxed -> False,
  FaceGrids -> {Bottom, Back, Left},
  ImageSize -> 400]
```

this is the code that I plot a matrix using `ListPlot3D`. The cuboids in it are not separate from each other, and the edges of the cuboid are fuzzy.

[image: my figure for matrix from the above code]

Comment: What code did you try, and in what way does the output "not look good?"

Comment: Thanks for adding the code.  Now, what don't you like about it?  Are you trying to reproduce the first as closely as possible, or is it more general?  Do you dislike the text, or the lack of the full box frame around the plot?  Put another way: define "nice."

Comment: Great thanks Wizard. I want to reproduce the first figure and do some improvement to it, such as the x&y ticks in the original figure do not in the middle of the bottom of the cuboid.

Answer (score 11):

If I have time later tonight I'll give you a graphic matching demo as I did for other users [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21123/making-a-presentable-barchart/21129#21129) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6212/121).

[As usual](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21134/121) I recommend building a specific graphic from `Graphics` (or `Graphics3D`) primitives so I suggest you spend some time reading about those, e.g. [`Cuboid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cuboid.html).

As a quick fix you can use `BarChart3D` as follows:

```
data = SparseArray[Tuples[{1, 4}, 2] -> 0.3, {4, 4}, 0.01];

chart = BarChart3D[data, ChartLayout -> "Grid"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are [*many* Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BarChart3D.html) you can use to customize this.  Please spend some time reading about those as well.  Once you get comfortable with graphics primitives and the internal format of these objects you can perform manipulations on the output to further customize them.

---

Okay, here is a fairly close approximation:

```
data = SparseArray[Tuples[{1, 4}, 2] -> 0.3, {4, 4}, 0.01];
data[[2 ;; 3, 2 ;; 3]] += 0.1;
data3D = Join @@ MapIndexed[Append[#2, #] &, data, {2}];

labels = {"VV", "VH", "HV", "HH"};

bar[n_][{x_, y_, z_}] := Cuboid[{x - n, y - n, 0}, {x + n, y + n, z}]
Graphics3D[
 bar[0.25] /@ data3D,
 Axes -> True,
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 19},
 Ticks -> {MapIndexed[{5 - #2[[1]], #} &, labels],
           MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, labels], 
           Automatic},
 FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 BoxStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2.5],
 PlotRangePadding -> 0.25,
 ViewPoint -> 1.5 {1.77, -2.29, 1.74},
 ImageSize -> 330
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The original:

[image: original]

Comment: +1 but how do you make a cuboid have a red top and blue sides?

Comment: @cormullion By changing the `Lighting`.  For example the default colors match the OP's image: `Graphics3D[Cuboid[]]`  or in all white:  `Graphics3D[Cuboid[], Lighting -> "Neutral"]`

Comment: Yes I suppose that's the only way...

Comment: @cormullion In newer versions there is `Texture`.

Comment: Not on a single face, though [apparently](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13483/61)

Answer (score 4):

```
 data = ({{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 8}, {2, 5, 7}});
 data = ArrayPad[data, {0, 1}];
 xTicks = {{1, "A"}, {2, "B"}, {3, "C"}};
 yTicks = {{1, "X"}, {2, "Y"}, {3, "Z"}};
 zTicks = {{0, "0"}, 0, {4, "4"}, {8, "8"}};
 pltstyl = {ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotRange -> {Min[data] - .2, Max[data] + 0.2}, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5}, Ticks -> {xTicks, yTicks, zTicks}, 
   Boxed -> False, FaceGrids -> {Bottom, Back, Left},  ImageSize -> 400};
```

**Using `BubbleChart3D` with a custom `ChartElementFunction`:**

```
(* transform data to a form acceptabele to BubbleChart3D:*)
bcdata =Join@@MapIndexed[Composition[Append[#, 1] &, Flatten, Reverse, List], data, {2}]; 
(* custom ChartElementFunction to produce cuboids with appropriate heights *)
ceFunc[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}, {zmin_, zmax_}}, v_, meta_] :=
  {Cuboid[{xmin, ymin, 0.}, {xmax, ymax, (zmax + zmin)/2}]};
BubbleChart3D[bcdata, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &), 
 ChartStyle -> Opacity[.9],
 ChartElementFunction -> ceFunc, BubbleSizes -> {0.15, .15}, 
 Evaluate@pltstyl]
```

[image]

**Post-processing `BubbleChart3D` to reshape the cuboids**

```
BubbleChart3D[bcdata, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &), 
 ChartStyle -> Opacity[.9], ChartElementFunction -> "Cube", BubbleSizes -> {0.15, .15}, 
 Evaluate@pltstyl] /. 
CuboidBox[{a_, b_, c_}, {e_, f_, g_},rest___]:>CuboidBox[{a, b, 0}, {e, f,(c + g)/2}, rest]
```

[image]

**Using `DiscretePlot3D` with `Interpolation`:**

```
(* interpolation of 3D data: *)
intF = Interpolation[Join @@ MapIndexed[Composition[Reverse, List], data, {2}]];
DiscretePlot3D[intF[i, j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}, 
ExtentSize -> Scaled[.75], Evaluate@pltstyl]
```

[image]

Comment: How to avoid the shift (empty space) between the cubes and the A B C axis?

Comment: @Thapanio, try removing the option `PlotRange` from the definition of `pltstyl` (or change it to `PlotRange -> All`).

Answer (score 2):

I tried to follow in the steps of the great Mr.Wizard, using cuboids, or rather polygons:

```
cuboid[origin_, box_List, colors_List] := 
 Module[
  {vertexList = {
     {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}, (* up *)
     {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, (* right *)
     {{0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, (* left *)
     {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}, (* front *) 
     {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}, (* back *)
     {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}} (* down *) 
   },
   (* scale *)
   vertexList = Map[Times[box, #] &, vertexList, {2}];
   (* move *)
   vertexList = Map[Plus[origin, #] &, vertexList, {2}];
   Riffle[colors, Polygon /@  vertexList]]
```

Then, with some suitable data:

```
fullData = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 3, 3}, {2, 1, 4}, 
    {2, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 6}, {3, 1, 7}, {3, 2, 8}, {3, 3, 9}};
xTicks = {{1.5, "A"}, {2.5, "B"}, {3.5, "C"}};
yTicks = {{1.5, "X"}, {2.5, "Y"}, {3.5, "Z"}};
zTicks = {{0, "0"}, 0, {4, "4"}, {8, "8"}};

Graphics3D[
 {
  cuboid[{#[[1]], #[[2]], 0}, {.5, .5, #[[3]]}, 
    {Cyan, Orange, LightGray, Purple, Gray, Gray}] & /@ fullData
  }, 
 Boxed -> True, 
 Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}},
 FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.4], Gray],
 PlotRange -> {-2, 10},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.7},
 Ticks -> {xTicks, yTicks, zTicks},
 FaceGrids -> {Bottom, Back, Left}
```

Each face has its own color.

[image: graphic]

With this sort of graphic, it's quite hard to read the heights accurately. But that's another story.

Comment: That was a bit of work! +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard the struggle is clearly visible... :)