# Histogram3D with various colors and textures on cuboids' faces

Tags: graphics3d, histograms, textures

I'm trying to produce an Histogram3D-like graph, but with a little more customization.

In particular I want to manually specify the color of each cuboid and to print some information on the top faces.

I did manage to do this, more or less, with a code like the following:

```
Graphics3D[{
  With[{data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}], 
    additionalHeight = 0.0001},
   Table[
    With[{color = Which[
        0 <= data[[i, o]] <= 0.2, Red,
        0.2 < data[[i, o]] <= 0.5, Orange,
        0.5 < data[[i, o]] <= 1, Green
        ]},
     {
        color, Cuboid[{i - 1/2, o - 1/2, 0}, {i + 1/2, o + 1/2, #}],
        Texture[
         Style[

          Column[{"in=" <> ToString@i, "out=" <> ToString@o}, Right, 
           Background -> color],
          Black, Bold
          ]
         ], EdgeForm[],
        Polygon[{{i - 0.4, o - 0.4, # + additionalHeight}, {i + 0.4, 
           o - 0.4, # + additionalHeight}, {i + 0.4, 
           o + 0.4, # + additionalHeight}, {i - 0.4, 
           o + 0.4, # + additionalHeight}},
         VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
        } &@data[[i, o]]
     ],
    {i, 10},
    {o, 10}
    ]
   ]
  },
 Axes -> True,
 ImageSize -> Large,
 RotationAction -> "Clip"
 ]
```

which produces the following:
[image]

However, as you can see, the output can definitely be better.
In particular I would like to remove those lines above and below each texture. 
I'm guessing they are due to the slight difference in height between the top face of the cuboid and the texture. However, removing this difference produces an even worse result.

Do you have any tip on how can this code be improved?

Comment: Related: [How can I imitate the style of a certain 3D bar chart?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21460/4678)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The existing answers show how to perfectly generate small textures on top of the cuboids. Unfortunately, the resulting 3D scene it is quite slow when you try to rotate it (about one frame per second).

I propose to use *one* `GraphicsComplex` object with only *one* texture (aka [atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas))

```
histogram[data_, cf_] := Module[{nx, ny},
   {nx, ny} = Dimensions@data;
   {coords, vtc} = 
    Outer[Plus, N@Tuples@Append[Range@{nx, ny}, {0}], 
       Tuples@{{-#, #}, {-#, #}, {0., 1.}}, 1] & /@ {.5, .4};
   coords[[;; , ;; , 3]] *= Flatten@data;
   coords = Flatten[coords, 1];
   vtc = (Flatten[vtc, 1][[;; , ;; 2]] - .5).{{1./nx, 0.}, {0., 1./ny}};
   polygons = 
    Flatten[#, 1] &@
     Outer[Plus, 
      Developer`ToPackedArray@{{1, 3, 7, 5}, {1, 5, 6, 2}, {5, 7, 8, 6}, {7, 3, 4, 
         8}, {3, 1, 2, 4}, {6, 8, 4, 2}}, 
      8 Transpose@Range[{0, 0, 0, 0}, nx ny - 1], 1];
   tex = Grid[
     Reverse@Array[
       Item[Column[{"in=" <> ToString@#2, "out=" <> ToString@#}, Right, 
          BaseStyle -> {Bold}], Background -> cf@data[[#2, #]]] &, {nx, ny}], 
     ItemSize -> {6.3, 6.3}, Spacings -> {0, 0}, Alignment -> Center {1, 1}];
   Graphics3D[{Texture[tex], 
     GraphicsComplex[coords, Polygon@polygons, VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc]}, 
    Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 700, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.2}]];


data = RandomReal[1, {10, 10}];
cf = Piecewise[{{Red, # <= 0.2}, {Orange, 0.2 < # <= 0.5}, {Green, # > 0.5}}] &;
histogram[data, cf]
```

[image]

I can seamlessly rotate even 100×100 grid (which looks like a [grass field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urGFc.gif)).

*Update:* better text visibility

Comment: This. Is. Magic!

Comment: Amazing clarity and rotation speed!

Answer (score 10):

For some reason those lines are created during the rasterization of the thing inside `Texture`:

```
Rasterize[
  Style[
    Column[{"in=" <> ToString@1, "out=" <> ToString@2}, Right, Background -> Green],
    Black,
    Bold
  ]
]
```

[image: rasterized image]

As you can see, the lines are part of the rasterized image's background. Manually rasterizing the thing inside `Texture` allows us to take control, e.g. overriding the default background colour:

```
Graphics3D[
  {
    With[
      {data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}], additionalHeight = 0.0001},
      Table[
        With[
          {
            color = Which[
              0 <= data[[i, o]] <= 0.2, Red,
              0.2 < data[[i, o]] <= 0.5, Orange,
              0.5 < data[[i, o]] <= 1, Green
            ]
          },
          {
            color,
            Cuboid[{i - 1/2, o - 1/2, 0}, {i + 1/2, o + 1/2, #}],
            Texture[
              Rasterize[#, Background -> color] & @ Style[
                Column[
                  {"in=" <> ToString @ i, "out=" <> ToString @ o},
                  Right,
                  Background -> color
                ],
                Black,
                Bold
              ]
            ],
            EdgeForm[],
            Polygon[
              {
                {i - 0.4, o - 0.4, # + additionalHeight},
                {i + 0.4, o - 0.4, # + additionalHeight},
                {i + 0.4, o + 0.4, # + additionalHeight},
                {i - 0.4, o + 0.4, # + additionalHeight}
              },
              VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}
            ]
          } & @ data[[i, o]]
        ],
        {i, 10},
        {o, 10}
      ]
    ]
  },
  Axes -> True,
  ImageSize -> Large,
  RotationAction -> "Clip"
]
```

[image: Lines removed]

Comment: Nice solution, but very slow

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get rid of the light-colored bars at the bottom and top by passing a `Graphics` object to `Texture`, and setting the `Background` on that, like so:

```
infoTexture[i_, o_, color_] :=
 With[{text = 
   Text@Column[{HoldForm["in" == i], HoldForm["out" == o]}, Right,
     BaseStyle -> {Bold}]},
  Texture@Graphics[
    text,
    Background -> color,
    ImageSize -> {40, 40}]];

Graphics3D[{With[{data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}], 
    additionalHeight = 0.0001}, 
    Table[With[{color = 
       Which[0 <= data[[i, o]] <= 0.2, Red, 0.2 < data[[i, o]] <= 0.5,
         Orange, 0.5 < data[[i, o]] <= 1, Green]}, {color,
        Cuboid[{i - 1/2, o - 1/2, 0}, {i + 1/2, o + 1/2, #}], 
        infoTexture[i, o, color], EdgeForm[], Green, 
        Polygon[{{i - 0.4, o - 0.4, # + additionalHeight}, {i + 0.4, 
          o - 0.4, # + additionalHeight}, {i + 0.4, 
          o + 0.4, # + additionalHeight}, {i - 0.4, 
          o + 0.4, # + additionalHeight}}, 
         VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
          {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]} &@data[[i, o]]], 
   {i, 10}, {o, 10}]]}, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
 RotationAction -> "Clip"]
```

This gives the following, and fairly quickly:

[image]

Picking the `ImageSize` for the `Graphics` object used to make the `Texture` was just a matter of trial and error.