# Typing the value of matrix elements in matrix plot

Tags: plotting, matrix, legending

I want to type the value of matrix elements when plotting it on the topside of the bar.

Example:
$$M=\left(\begin{matrix}
0.77 & 0.04 & 0.01 & 0.0\\
0.04 & 0.81 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
0.02 & 0.0 & 0.81 & 0.08\\
0.0 & 0.07 & 0.04 & 0.93
\end{matrix}\right)$$

the output:

[image]

my code:

```
exp1 = ( {
   {0.77, 0.04, 0.01, 0.0},
   {0.04, 0.81, 0.0, 0.0},
   {0.02, 0.0, 0.81, 0.08},
   {0.0, 0.07, 0.04, 0.93}
  } )
data = ArrayPad[Abs[exp1], {0, 1}];
DATAAA1 = 
 ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> Full, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> {Opacity[0.7]}, 
  ColorFunction -> "IslandColors", PlotRange -> All, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, DataRange -> All, ImageSize -> 600, 
  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.9], Blue], 
  AxesLabel -> {Text[Rotate["Input", -10 Degree]], 
    Text[Rotate["Output", 60 Degree]], 
    Text[Rotate["Probability", 100 Degree]]}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, 12], Boxed -> False]
```

the result i have:
[image]

### Edit

There are complicated solutions that manually construct a `Graphics3D` object, but can there be a simple solution using standard functions?

### Edit 2

I found a manual solution using the following latex code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={17cm, 25cm}]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.085mm}
    \begin{picture}(800,250)\linethickness{0.3mm}
        \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm]{sample.eps}
        \put(-490,380){\scriptsize$0.77$}
        \put(-350,410){\scriptsize$0.81$}
        \put(-220,430){\scriptsize$0.81$}
        \put(-90,490){\scriptsize$0.93$}
    \end{picture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

the output:

[image]

but I am still searching for an automated way on Mathematica to solve the problem.

Comment: Similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98687/histogram3d-with-various-colors-and-textures-on-cuboids-faces/98822#98822).

Comment: Please provide your data. Look at the `Histogram3D` documentation, in particular *Options/ChartLabels*. There are good examples.

Comment: I added a sample of the code.

Comment: I added a manual solution using latex but an automated one is better.

Comment: @Thapanio Try this `rest = exp1 - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[exp1]];
r = Flatten[Table[n = Round[rest[[i, j]]*100];
    ConstantArray[{i, j}, n]
    , {i, 4}, {j, 4}], 2];
d = Table[n = Round[exp1[[i, i]]*100];
   ConstantArray[{i, i}, n], {i, 4}];
Histogram3D[Join[d, {r}], Automatic, "Probability", PlotRange -> All, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[Diagonal[exp1], Above, "Framed"],
 PlotTheme -> {"Marketing", "NoAxes"}]`

Comment: That is quite suitable. Thank you.