# Plotting a Set of Three Points with Histogram3D

Tags: plotting, histograms, charts

I would like to know whether I can use `Histogram3D` to plot a set of points with three given values. I want to plot the values {0, 0, 0.01}, {0, 1, 0.1}, {1, 0, 0.02}, {1, 1, 0.1} using Histogram3D. I tried the following command `Histogram3D[{{0, 0, 0.01}, {0, 1, 0.1}, {1, 0, 0.02}, {1, 1, 0.1}}]` but I wasn't successful! I also tried importing these values from an CSV file but also didn't work. Is there a way I can simply plot three values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I imitate the style of a certain 3D bar chart?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21460/how-can-i-imitate-the-style-of-a-certain-3d-bar-chart)

Comment: Try `Histogram3D[RandomChoice[{0.01, 0.02, 0.1, 0.1} -> {{0,0}, {1,0}, {0,1},{1,1}}, 1000]]`

Comment: Actually, I don’t want to create random numbers. I have the x,y,z values. We have 100 elements. The x and y are integers that have the following values 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. The z values are real numbers that range between 0.0 and 1.0. We can think of it as a matrix for each xy element we have a z value. But I want to plot them using Histogram3D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A data set of 100 triples:

```
xy = Tuples[Range[0, 9], 2];
SeedRandom[1]
z = RandomReal[1, 100];
xyz = Join[xy, List /@ z, 2];
```

Construct a [`WeightedData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) object from the list `xyz` using the first two columns as values and the last column as weights:

```
wd = WeightedData[xyz[[All, ;; 2]], xyz[[All, -1]]];
```

Use `wd` with `Histogram3D`:

```
Histogram3D[wd, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Add the option `ChartElementFunction -> "Cylinder"` to get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you are looking for something like this:

```
data = {{0, 0, 0.01}, {0, 1, 0.1}, {1, 0, 0.02}, {1, 1, 0.1}};
bars =
  With[{r = .25},
   Tooltip[Cylinder[{{#1, #2, 0}, {#1, #2, #3}}, r], {#1, #2, #3}] & @@@ data];
Graphics3D[bars, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: chart]