# Unwanted gap in ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I tried an answer on the post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21508/32332) and I had an unwanted gap (see attached picture)

[image]
**Does anyone know how to avoid this gap?**

Comment: try removing the option `PlotRange` from the definition of `pltstyl` (or change it to `PlotRange -> All`)

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I changed the limits of PlotRange to ->All.

Comment: Should I post a code for the solution?

Comment: Thapanio, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help from @kglr, I managed to find a solution.

The main change to eliminate the gap **PlotRange->All**

```
data=any random matrix
data2=ArrayPad[data,{0,1}];
ListPlot3D[data2,Mesh-> Full,InterpolationOrder->0,Filling->Bottom,
FillingStyle->{Opacity[0.7]},ColorFunction->"IslandColors",PlotRange->All,
DataRange->All,FaceGrids->{Bottom,Back,Left},ImageSize->400,PlotTheme->"Monochrome",
PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[0.9],Blue]]
```

[image]